# ::before selector not working

Tags: css, pseudo-element

I have spent almost two hours trying to figure this out. Can anyone provide any insight into making the ::before selector work?

Relevant html:

```
<body><section><article><div>   
<h2>What Others Have Said...</h2>
    <div class="centered">
        <h3 class="reviewExcerpt"><p>The services were awesome</p>
        </h3>
        <div class="5 floatRight">
            <p>&mdash; Anonymous</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div></article></section></body>
```

Relevant CSS:

```
.reviewExcerpt p::after {
  content: "\00A0.\00A0.\00A0.";
}
.5 p::before {
  content: "5 stars";
  font-family: 'Font Awesome';
  display:block;
}
.floatRight {
  float: right;
  display: block;
}
h3 {
  font-family: 'Raleway', script, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.6em;
  line-height: 1em;
  margin: .8em 0 0;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #555555;
}
h2 {
  font-family: 'Raleway', script, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.9em;
  margin: .8em 0 .25em;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #b565a7;
}
.centered {
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;  
}
```

JS fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/k6y07r45/

The code shows ::after working just a couple lines up.

Comment: Selectors can't start with a number.

Comment: Rename `.5` to something valid, starting with a character.

Comment: It's always something simple, isn't it. Thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSS Selectors (class [.] or ID [#]) cannot start with a number.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448981/what-characters-are-valid-in-css-class-names-selectors) SO question provides some insight on the required grammar if you want to explore it.

I updated your [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k6y07r45/1/), changing your class `.5` to `.a-5`. You should also think about making your classes more semantic, to give you and anyone else reading your code clarity on complex projects. For instance, `rating` is a lot more meaningful than `5` (not to mention valid).

It's also worth noting right now that ::before and ::after can only select [non-replaced elements](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/replacedelements). This doesn't affect what you're doing right now, but since you're experimenting that's another tidbit to remember.